# How to update the old database file with the new database file in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-layout

I am having an application which i uses sqlite .db in that. I am having a existing Database file in that application . So now what i have to do is i have to make a connection and i should download the new .db file and i have to replace the existing .db with the new .db file that i had downloaded.

I am keeping my .db file in the assests folder of the application . People are saying it is only Readable folder and we cant delete any file from that folder .

So please let me know how to solve this problem .

Answer (score 0):

you can change the DatabaseHelper class constructor for updating the database name,Version number is very important.

```
 public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbName, null, int dbVersion)
```

{

```
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}
```

instead of using like this

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}
```